# How to make permanent auto select intellisense results sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server, autocomplete, intellisense, sql-server-2012, ssms

Right now it is filling results via intellisense as you type
But it is not auto selecting

When you hit `ctrl + alt + space` at the same time, it starts auto selecting as you type for only that query

I want this feature to be permanent

Here image of both scenario

no auto select

[image]

auto select enabled (i want this permanent)

[image]

Comment: This should be fixed in an upcoming release:
http://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/686087/intellisense-completion-mode-does-not-persist

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if this is possible in SSMS 2012.

You might want to try some 3rd party tools such as [SQL Prompt](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/sql-prompt/) or [ApexSQL Complete](http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_complete.aspx)

Comment: wow this sucks so bad. it was like that even in sql 2008 if i remember correctly.